# Making a metapackage that depends on a package with a different architecture

Tags: packaging

I'm making a metapackage to install a number of packages that comprise my standard setup, like the package `ubuntu-desktop`.  One package that I'd like to install is [Adobe Reader][1], which has a deb.  I've added this deb to my custom repo (using `reprepro`), and it installs fine by itself.  However, when I attempt to install the metapackage, which `Depends` on `adobereader-enu`, `apt-get install metapackage` says

```
metapackage: Depends: adobereader-enu but it is not installable
```

I suspect this is because `adobereader-enu` is i386-only, and this is a amd64 system.  The metapackage itself is basically just a control file, so it's `Architecture: all`.  I'm wondering if there's a conflict here, and if so, how to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done, unless `adobereader-enu` declares itself to be `MultiArch: allowed` or `MultiArch: foreign`.

Instead, create an i386-only metapackage, which depends on `adobereader-enu`, and is `MultiArch: allowed`.

Comment: This looks good.  I'm marking it correct without testing, and will report back later.